# WordPress Posts from next page?

Tags: wordpress

If I have `query_posts()` construction, which loading 10 posts per page with pagination, how can I load posts from next page? For example:

First page: posts on this page + posts on page 2

Second page: posts on page 2 + posts on page 3
etc.

My current code:

```
<?php
    $current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
    $params = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => 10, 
        'category_name' => 'stati', 
        'paged' => $current_page ); 
    query_posts($params); 
    $wp_query->is_archive = true; 
    $wp_query->is_home = false; while(have_posts()): the_post(); 
?> 
<div class="article-item"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2></div> 
<?php endwhile; the_posts_pagination( array('prev_next' => false));?>
```

I've tried to make query inside query, but it didn't work - the result is an infinite loop which prints only first post (and actually I understand it can't be the right solution, but I don't get which will be right):

```
<?php
    $current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
    $params = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => 10, 
        'category_name' => 'stati', 
        'paged' => $current_page ); 
    query_posts($params); 
    $wp_query->is_archive = true; 
    $wp_query->is_home = false; while(have_posts()): the_post(); 
?> 
<div class="article-item"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2></div> 
    <?php
        $inner_args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'category_name'       => 'stati',
            'paged'           => $current_page + 1);
        $inner_query = new WP_Query($inner_args);
        while ($inner_query->have_posts()) :
    ?>
    <div class="preview-article-item"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></div>
    <?php
        endwhile;
    ?>
<?php endwhile; the_posts_pagination( array('prev_next' => false));?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry for this. I've updated question.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this? why not just increase `posts_per_page` value if you want to display more posts?

Comment: Seems like increasing posts per page should be the answer. And if you really want the result you describe, I wonder if you'd have more success altering the number of posts that the pagination links skip. That is, have 20 posts per page but make your pagination only navigate by 10s

Comment: There has to be a preview of posts on the next page that the user can see these posts before he goes to next page. I'll try change number of posts and pagination values, it seems like solution of my problem. Thank you. And thanks all for your answers.